# losing transparency when using imageinputstream and bufferedimage to create png strip from gif animation

Tags: java, png, transparency, bufferedimage, animated-gif

I was finally able to write the following code which takes a animated GIF and converts it to a png strip. however for some reason it loses the transparency from the original gif. Can someone advise how i can keep the transparency

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Object input = new File("C:\\Users\\drizzt\\Documents\\jax.gif");
    // or Object input = new FileInputStream("animated.gif");
    ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
    Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
    if (!readers.hasNext())
        throw new RuntimeException("no image reader found");
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
    reader.setInput(stream); // don't omit this line!
    int n = reader.getNumImages(true); // don't use false!
    int h = reader.getHeight(0);
    int w = reader.getWidth(0);

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w * n, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    boolean[] imagedrawn;
    imagedrawn = new boolean[n];

    // big.drawImage(outputimage, w*i, 0, null);

    System.out.println("numImages = " + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
        System.out.println("image[" + i + "] = " + image);
        // img = BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // img.createGraphics()
        imagedrawn[i] = img.createGraphics().drawImage(image, w * i, 0,
                null);

    }

    try {
        // retrieve image
        // BufferedImage bi = getMyImage();
        File outputfile = new File("c:\\saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    stream.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w * n, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

with

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w * n, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

...and you'll have transparency.

Possibly better yet, is to do:

```
BufferedImage img = reader.getRawImageType(0).createBufferedImage(w * n, h);
```

Then you'll keep the exact image layout from the GIF, and possibly get a smaller output image (a minor detail here, is that `getRawImageType` may return `null` if there's no corresponding color space in Java, but this should probably never happen for a GIF).

Unrelated to the issue, but still good practice: Whenever you do `img.createGraphics()` you should also call `dispose()` on the `Graphics2D` when done painting. Move the `createGraphics()` outside the loop and `dispose` after the loop for better performance.

It's even possible to avoid the drawing altogether, and read the contents of each frame directly into `img`, by replacing your loop with something like this:

```
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
param.setDestination(img);

for (int i = 0; i++; i < n) {
    param.setDestinationOffset(new Point(w * i, 0);
    reader.read(i, param);
}
```

Comment: I tried TYPE-INT_ARGB as you suggested and it worked. I stopped there as I just need the png strip for another project. Thanks!